# Testrigor CI/CD RESULT:OK Dont trigger test

Tags: testrigor

Team 
Im using the script on CI/CD tab for the integration with Github Actions (Ubuntu-latest)
The issue is when i try to run labeled test all the request give me:

```
{
  "result": "ok",
  "queueId": "QUEUEID"
}
```

But there is not any test running after make that request, So i try testing this things
1.- Run the without labels to run all test (It Works)
2.- Then i try with a one labeled test like

`"labels":[ "mobile" ]  or "labels":"mobile"`
Give me the same  result as upper example result: ok but does'nt trigger any test

2.1.- Try with a 2 labeled test

`"labels":[ "mobile" , "login"]`

and still the same.

So, there is any way that i can see the logs from your side, or any way that i can check why its not triggering the test

Some examples that i've been trying

```
curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'auth-token: TR_AUTH_TOKEN' \
  --data '{ "fileUrl":"URL_TEST_TO_A_PUBLIC_CLOUD", "labels":["Mobile","Login" ] }' \
  https://api.testrigor.com/api/v1/apps/TEST_CASES_ID/retest

curl -X POST \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'auth-token: TR_AUTH_TOKEN' \
  --data '{ "fileUrl":"URL_TEST_TO_A_PUBLIC_CLOUD", "forceCancelPreviousTesting":true, "storedValues":{"storedValueName1":"Value"}, "labels":["Mobile","Login" ] }' \
  https://api.testrigor.com/api/v1/apps/TEST_CASES_ID/retest
```

PD: This is for android tests

Answer (score 0):

The tests will trigger eventually. Once you do the API call the system needs to download your APK, then start the emulator, upload APK to the emulator and start the APK.

This all takes a bit of time and your task might be in queue if you are using a free version of testRigor.

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger a retest and you specify certain labels to be considered, you won't see the run in the main view, there you can see only the last run that was triggered for all the test cases in the suite. Label/branch tests will be listed in `All Runs` option on the left menu.